# Ubuntu 12.04.2 won't boot after bumblebee instalation

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics, bumblebee

First of all sorry for my English, it's not my first language.

Here is what I have done:

I had a working ubuntu 12.04 with all updates and working bumblebee, so I could do optirun command and battery life was better than without bumblebee.

Than I decided to reinstall both my systems installed windows 7 and ubuntu.

Reinstalled Windows 7 all working as expected, than on other partition installed ubuntu 12.04. All worked perfectly. Than I installed bumblebee according to the procedure written here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee same steps that I used before.

But now after I install drivers and do all written in procedure and I reboot my notebook system won't boot, it is simply stuck at black screen after short showing of start screen.

I reinstalled ubuntu many times already and tried everthing, but when I try install nvidia drivers it won't boot after shutting down notebook and only thing I can do is reinstalling system.

I have Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E530 and processor: Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU and graphic cards are Intel HD 4000 and Nvidia geforce gt630m

After clean install without bumblebee, terminal command `lspci| grep VGA` is showing:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0de9 (rev a1)
```

Can you suggest a sollution?? Or at least some links to similar topics??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04.02 ships with a [Hardware enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack). Basically this is a stack providing kernel/xorg from Quantal (packages `linux-generic-lts-quantal` and `xserver-xorg-lts-quantal`) to improve hardware support.

What probably happened when you installed Bumblebee is that, because it depends on the default Xorg stack, `xserver-xorg-lts-quantal` was removed and replaced with `xserver-xorg`, and those two stacks don't seem to work well when mixed.

To fix this you need to boot in text mode. The easiest way is to achieve this is pressing <kbd>E</kbd> when you highlight your Ubuntu entry on Grub. This will let you edit the entry (non permanently). There you should see a line similar to this:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=(...)  ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

Replace the `quiet splash $vt_handoff` with `text` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. This should boot you in text mode. After login you have to choose what to do next:

1. Revert the changes you made: this will remove Bumblebee and  let you start your system again. You will only be able to install Bumblebee without breaking the system when someone fixes Bumblebee dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-quantal linux-generic-lts-quantal
   ```
2. Remove the Hardware Enablement stack. This will let you install Bumblebee.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic xserver-xorg
   ```

Either one of those options will install a lot of packages and remove others, so you will need to have internet access. Also if you have important information make a backup before you proceed.

I had the same problem and used the second option, and everything works now. I have not tried the first option, but it should work as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will try it ASAP. I don't have time now because of school.

Comment: I tried your advices but it didn't worked. But you are right, it was because of hardware enablement stack packed with ubuntu 12.04.02.. So I downloaded ubuntu 12.04.01 from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ and all is working now :))
Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: I ran into exactly that problem just now, and blindly fixed it by reinstalling the "old" xserver. @Andrej you should really select Salem's answer as the correct one.

Comment: Selected as correct...sorry forgot about it...