# If i install ubuntu 12.04.1 will I receive all updates without upgrading to ubuntu 12.04.2 due to bumblebee issue?

Tags: dependencies, bumblebee

I ran into the problem with the bumblebee dependencies for the Ubuntu 12.04.2. To know more about the problem you can head to this thread [Ubuntu 12.04.2 won't boot after bumblebee instalation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256995/ubuntu-12-04-2-wont-boot-after-bumblebee-instalation)

While my question is the following, if i install ubuntu 12.04.1 from old releases web site will I still receive all the updates excluding hardware stack from quantal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12.04.1 will be updated as normal without the new kernel (3.5.xx) or X-server from Quantal. 
So no problem there.

Comment: alright, thanks. I will mark question answered in 10 min only thou :P